# How can I make wide spaces to single space? Java String

Tags: java, string, substring

For example, I input "i Am Going \s\s\s to go tO the mall" the wide spaces(\s) must turn into single space.

```
    String f = line.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + line.substring(1).toLowerCase();


    String[] split = f.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){

        System.out.print (split[i] + " ");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the wide spaces(\t) must turn into single space"? Can you provide expected result? How is it different from what you already get? For now it sounds like you want to *replace* each `\t` with single space which can be done via `String replaced = yourString.replace("\t", " ");`.

Comment: By "wide spaces" do you mean _tabs_?

Comment: @khelwood just wide spaces. I meant "i am going \\s \\s \\s \\s to the mall"

Comment: So why does your question say `\t` several times?

Comment: @khelwood I label \t to justify but anyway, do you have any idea turning wide spacing to single space?

Comment: Do you mean to replace sequences of spaces with single spaces?

Comment: @khelwood yes sir

Comment: So something like `String singleSpaceOnly = yourString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");`? (add `trim()` if you also want to remove leading and trailing spaces).

Comment: What should happen with single tabulators? Should they also be replaced with single space, or do you want to leave them?

Comment: Thank you so much guys!! Now it works!!

Comment: @Pshemo yea can do so. But is there any way aside from .replaceAll?

Comment: You can always write your own loop, but replaceAll is simpler (if you know regex).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `String toTitleCase(String)` method that does the right thing to *one* word. It should handle special cases like turning `tO` to `to`, and keeping `the` lowercase, keeping all caps like `FBI` intact, and handle names like `O'Neal`, etc.

You can consider looking for an existing implementation instead.

Then do as you do: split the string, convert, join back:

```java
String result = Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
                .map(this::toTitleCase)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir.  My problem right now sir is that if I am going to input big spaces, the sentence must be turn in to single spacing. How will I do it?

Comment: Perhaps add a filter to avoid trimmed strings of length 0 from being included.

Comment: @AndrewS I tried .trim() to  but doesn't work.

Comment: Add the filter to the stream, before the mapping, e.g.: `..)).filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty()).map(...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **String object methods** and **regexp** together.
Example:

```
String str1 = "i Am Going \t \t to go tO the mall";

//note : trim() eliminates only spaces at the beginning and end of the String
//removes extra spaces
String str2 = str1.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "); //way(1)
String str2 = str1.trim().replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " "); //way(2)

str2 = str1.replaceAll("\t", " "); //convert tab to space
str2 = str1.toLowerCase(); //convert all chars to lower case
str2 = str1.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str1.substring(1); //convert first character to uppercase
```

Also you can use `org.apache.commons:commons-lang` library to **capitalize** your string simply:

```
StringUtils.capitalize(yourString);
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. You may be on right track but please run your code first before posting it to see if it actually work.

Comment: Thanks sir. My code shown above is working but to remove the extra spaces is the thing I can't make to do. I tried your algo in removing, however output still the same.

Comment: @Pshemo I know Strings are immutable!It was only a hint!